# Android studio directory creation

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, directory

I am working on a project in Android Studio. Whenever I try to create a new resource directory under the default `/res` directory it doesn't appear on the project scope, but it does appear on the packages scope. How can that be? Also, whenever I try to create a layout file (XML) in the directory I create, the file that is created is not placed under the selected and desired directory.

Hope it makes sense with an example.I got these:

```
/app/res/layout
/app/res/layout-land
/app/res/layout-large
```

If I create a file in `/layout-land`, Android IDE places it in the `/layout` directory.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created the the layout-land folder it is not shown in the project view, however if you right click on the res folder and choose to show in project explorer you can see the folder has been created there as you have pointed out.

When you add an XML file to this layout-land folder (copy and paste the XML file in the existing layout folder), the XML file should become visible in the res/layout folder in the project view with (land) after it to indicate it is the landscape XML file.

Comment: I did your steps, and I just found out that instead of having a landscape and a portrait folder, android studio will create a folder under each layout that has both configurations... so there is still only one layout folder, and many sublayouts folders

Comment: Please see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a lot of testing trying every button in Android Studio I Knew how to do it.

In my case I wanted to create a folder **layout-port** and inside that folder two xml files: activity_main.xml and detail_activity.xml but every time  I tried to add a xml file that was created in **layout** folder.

To create in **layout_port** folder I had to right click in layout-port then choose **New -> Layout Resources File** like the image below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please see this insctruction for different layout orientation:

[image]

[image]

You can switch between layouts in the designer as you can see on the pictures.